# Django: filter by DateField with db_index is a lot slower than filter by DateTimeField without db_index

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

In one of my models I have the following fields:

```
creation_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
creation_date = models.DateField(db_index=True, auto_now_add=True)
```

If I do the following filter using the creation time (DateTimeField field):

```
User.objects.filter(id__in=user_ids, creation_time__range=[start_date, end_date]).count()
```

It takes few ms to run, as expected. But if I do the same filter on the creation date (DateField field with db index):

```
User.objects.filter(id__in=user_ids, creation_date__range=[start_date, end_date]).count()
```

It takes *few minutes* to finish... Eventually I get almost the same result as above, but after a long time.

I though both fields are stored the same way in the DB and the only difference is how django serialize / deserialize them into Python objects (and ofc date field getting default midnight time).

So why using the date field is so much slower? Is it because of the db_index (if so, why)?

EDIT: their SQL query looks essentially the same btw:

```
>>> print User.objects.filter(id__in=user_ids, creation_time__range=[start_date, end_date]).query
SELECT "users_user"."id", "users_user"."uuid", "users_user"."creation_time", "users_user"."ip", "users_user"."user_agent", "users_user"."hash", "users_user"."creation_date", "users_user"."is_bot" FROM "users_user" WHERE ("users_user"."id" IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) AND "users_user"."creation_time" BETWEEN 2017-07-18 00:00:00 AND 2017-07-19 00:00:00)

>>> print User.objects.filter(id__in=user_ids, creation_date__range=[start_date, end_date]).query
SELECT "users_user"."id", "users_user"."uuid", "users_user"."creation_time", "users_user"."ip", "users_user"."user_agent", "users_user"."hash", "users_user"."creation_date", "users_user"."is_bot" FROM "users_user" WHERE ("users_user"."id" IN (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) AND "users_user"."creation_date" BETWEEN 2017-07-18 AND 2017-07-19)
```

Thanks,

Comment: use the `query()` method of a QuerySet to get the plain SQL statement, and check the execution plan for both queries.

Comment: @alfonso.kim Looks pretty much the same :/ Thanks though.

Comment: Run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on the queries.

Comment: Did you happen to solve the mystery? I'm curious to know the reason.